# print_rows(num_rows=m, num_columns=n) in graphlab / turi not working

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, rows, nearest-neighbor, graphlab

I using jupyter notebook and graphlab / turi for tfidf-nearest_neighbors model, which works fine so far.

However, when I query the model like

tfidf_model.query(Test_AD)
I always just get the head - [5 rows x 4 columns]

I am supposed to use "print_rows(num_rows=m, num_columns=n)" to print more rows and columns like:

tfidf_model.query(Test_AD).print_rows(num_rows=50, num_columns=4)

however, when I used it, I dont get any rows anymore, only the summary field:

Starting pairwise querying.
+--------------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| Query points | # Pairs | % Complete. | Elapsed Time |
+--------------+---------+-------------+--------------+
| 0            | 1       | 0.00519481  | 13.033ms     |
| Done         |         | 100         | 106.281ms    |
+--------------+---------+-------------+--------------+

That's it. No error message, nothing. Any Ideas, how to get all/ more rows?

I tried to convert into pandas or .show() command etc., didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

ok, well, seems like I have to define the number or neighbours with:

tfidf_model.query(Test_AD, k=100).show()

so I can get a list of first 100 in the canvass.

Answer (score 0):

This situation happens due to inability of Jupyter Notebook to show every line in a same frame. There are several ways to print and see your requirements.

1. Select range using SFrame. For Example: -

   ```
   sf[100:] # Returns an SFrame containing rows 100 to the end
   sf[:100] # Returns an SFrame containing rows 0 to row 99 inclusive
   sf[0:100:2] # Returns an SFrame containing rows 0 to row 100 in steps of 2
   sf[-100:] # Returns an SFrame containing last 100 rows
   sf[-100:len(sf):2] # Returns an SFrame containing last 100 rows in steps of 2
   ```
2. You may also convert SFrame to data frame, slice the data and printing. Ex.

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame({i: range(1000) for i in range(100)})
   df.ix[:5, :10]
   ```
3. You may also play with head and tail:-

   ```
   df.head(n)
   df.tail(n)
   ```
4. You can output the data and save in some file like .csv/ .xls file and see your results. Ex.

   ```
   SFrame.export_csv(filename, delimiter=', ', line_terminator='\n', header=True, quote_level=2, double_quote=True, escape_char='\\', quote_char='"', na_rep='', file_header='', file_footer='', line_prefix='', _no_prefix_on_first_value=False, **kwargs)
   ```

Please refer to the documentation on SFrame. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

*print_rows* is intended method on a Sframe or a model. Here is example for a model:

```
model1.get("coefficients").print_rows(num_rows=16, num_columns=6)
```